# Creating a list of unique items from a list of lists iteratively

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of unique items from a list of lists by selecting one item  from each list, and if an item in a list is already in the unique item list, then select the second  unique item and so on.See list and my attempt below;

```
mylist=`[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

def unique(lists):
    uniquelst=[]
    for _lst in lists:
        if _lst[0] not in uniquelst:
            uniquelst.append(_lst[0])
        else:
            uniquelst.append(_lst[1])

    return uniquelst
```

my output: `[1, 2, 2]`

Expected output: `[1, 2, 3]`

Only one item to be selected from each list, hence the appropriate solution should be able to produce the same result for this example `[[1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3]]` Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest he gets 1,2,2 instead of 1,2,3.

Comment: @selten98, yes, that was optical mistake

Comment: Does the expected output have to contain one item of each list?

Comment: @rodrigo, it has to contain one item from each list, thats why some of these solutions would not work under different conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the restrictions you mentioned this code should work -

```
def unique(lists):
    uniquelst = []
    for lst in lists:
        for elem in lst:
            if elem not in uniquelst:
                uniquelst.append(elem)
                break

    return uniquelst
```

The second loop iterates over elements of the inner list and check if they are already present in `uniquelst`. In case they are not present, add the element and break from inner loop.

One thing I forgot to mention is that this code assumes the elements of inner list are in sorted order. If that is not the case, please sort inner list using `sorted()` or `sort()` before the second loop

Comment: @Boby, can you try the two loop solution I've mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]
print(list(set(flat_list)))
```

Answer (score 5):

With [***set***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) object and [**itertools.chain(*iterables)***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function:

```
import itertools

mylist = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
result = set(itertools.chain(*mylist))
print(list(result))
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: you solution would not work under other conditions; for example `[[1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: @kuro, Roman's method failed under when presented with the new example, it produced this result `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` instead of `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @Boby, you are right. Totally overlooked the restriction

Comment: @kuro, I tried virtually all the solutions recommended here before posting the question. Hence I'm still waiting for the right  answer

Comment: @Boby, I suppose, your description seemed confusing to me. I rely on the phrase *create a list of unique items from a list of lists*

Comment: @Boby, why the last example `[[1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3]]`  should not become `[1, 4, 3]` as it was the 1st sublist?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, the last example was only there as a guide to ensure a generalised solution is obtained

Comment: @Boby, you mean the steps should be `_lst[0]` - `_lst[1]` - `_lst[2]` ?

Comment: @Boby, but that steps would not be applicable for such input `[[1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 4]]` as the last sublist would not have `_lst[2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
newlist = []
for l in mylist:
    newlist = newlist + l
return list(set(newlist))
```

Does this help you?